# Routing for requests which are not saved into routes

Tags: laravel

I want all requests for which there is no route to be checked for the length of the characters after the domain.
If the number is less than 5, a certain controller with a certain action should be called and if it is >=5, another controller and action should be called.

Sample:
1.
https://test.com/abcd
should be use this controller/action
controller: color
action: colortype

2.
https://test.com/aabbc
should use this controller/action
controler: car
action: type

3.
https://test.com/infos
should call infos controller, because there is a route saved into web.php or api.php

How can I realize it?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I haven't tested but if you put your logic in the form Regular expression then this might help you [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Comment: Is there any pattern to the `parameter` at the end of the domain (i.e. do you know what value(s) you might expect)? Are you going to have more than just the two use cases you've outlined above? Will you eventually need it to work for `Animals` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another Way with **Regex**:

```
Route::get('infos',[InfosController::class, 'infoAction']);
    
    
Route::get('{lessThan5}', [InfosController::class, 'colorAction'])
->where('lessThan5', '^(.{1,4})');


Route::get('{greatherThan5}', [InfosController::class, 'typeAction'])
->where('greatherThan5', '^(.{5,})');
```

**InfosController :**

```
public function typeAction($greatherThan5)
{
    return $greatherThan5;
```

Comment: Into this cases I want to push the parameter to the action. How can I do it?

Route::get('{lessThan5}', [InfosController::class, 'colorAction'])
->where('lessThan5', '^(.{1,4})');


Route::get('{greatherThan5}', [InfosController::class, 'typeAction'])
->where('greatherThan5', '^(.{5,})');

Comment: @Mondy I update my answer with controller method

Answer (score 1):

You can use `controller redirection` for it

In `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/{text}', function ($text){
    if ($text == 'infos'){
        return redirect()->action([InfosController::class, 'infoAction']);
    }
    
    if (strlen($text) >= 5){
        return redirect()->action([ActionController::class, 'carAction']);
    }

    return redirect()->action([ActionController::class, 'colorAction']);
});
```

Or you can offload it to middleware class

Comment: A small opinionated change I would suggest; you don't need to nest the second `if` in an `else`.

Comment: I do get an error:
InvalidArgumentException
Action App\Http\Controllers\ActionController@carAction not defined.

Comment: Because you don't have `carAction` method in `ActionController`. You have to change controller and method names to your one. I wrote them as an example